How do i change the text in a text label when a player is changing teams and interacting a proximity prompt (LUA)
So i wanted to change the text label when a player is switching teams or is in a team that satisfy my code's condition. Also, when a player is interacting with a proximity prompt.
Problem:
It didnt change.. nothing is showing in the console.
Basically i tried adding some debug statements but again it didnt show up.
Note: Yes that is the literal names of the team
local function updateText(message)
        textObject.Text = message
    end

local function updateTextOnTeamChange(player)
    local teamService = game:GetService("Teams")
    if teamService then
        local playerTeam = teamService:GetPlayerTeam(player)
        if playerTeam then
            local teamName = playerTeam.Name
            if teamName == "Starting Point <3" then 
                updateText("Enter a portal to start~!")
            elseif teamName == " Playing  ~ !!" then 
                updateText("Checkpoint : ")
            elseif teamName == "Finish Line ^w^" then 
                updateText("You finished the tower!")
            else
                updateText("An error occurred!")
                warn("Unknown player team: " .. teamName)
            end
        else
            updateText("You are not on any team")
        end
    else
        warn("Teams service not found!")
        updateText("An error occurred! Please try again later.")
    end 
end game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    print("Player added:", player.Name) -- Debugging statement
    player:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Team"):Connect(function()
        print("Team changed for player:", player.Name) -- Debugging statement
        updateTextOnTeamChange(player)
    end)
end)

this is for the proximity prompt
local trigger = checkpoint:FindFirstChild("ProximityPrompt")
            if trigger then
                trigger.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
                    if player == game.Players.LocalPlayer then
                        print("Checkpoint triggered successfully.. Proceeding to update checkpoint " .. checkpoint.Name)
                        checkpoint.Transparency = 1
                        updateText("Checkpoint: " .. checkpoint.Name)
                    else
                        updateText("Error occurred!")
                        warn("Objects not found")
                    end
                end)
            end

any feedbacks is greatly appreciated ~!!!

You cannot edit the player UI from the server, you must do it client sided

The script is local and is under the textlabel that updates it accordingly.
